# Unix Shell Scripting output to an Excel File

Tags: shell-script

I have a Shell script with Multiple SQL statements like this:

```
select Count(*) from Emp where date= current_date-1;
```

After executing the Shell script i need a MS excel file to be create with Column name
(as shown below) and result in my local system and also it has to be mailed to my mail id.

Ms Excel File:

```
X(Table name)  - Eg: Emp
Result set           120
```

Comment: MS Excel output Should be like  Column1- Columnname( Table name mentioned in Select query) in first line and  result set in sexond line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"; print "Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6"};
     NR > 1{print "IND", "INR", $6, $7, $8, $9;}' Inputdata.txt > Output.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql statement to contain table name as well

```
sqlplus <USER_NAME>/<PASSWORD>@<DB_NAME> <<! > output.dat
SET PAGES 0
select 'Emp,' || Count(*) from Emp where date= current_date-1;
EXIT;
!
```

```
awk -F "," '{ a[++n] = $1; b[n] = $2; next }
END { printf "Table Name"; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf ",%s", a[i]; print"";
           printf "Result Set"; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf ",%s", b[i]; print ""
}' output.dat > output.csv

uuencode output.csv output.csv | mail -s "Query result" "toemail@domain.com"
```

Comment: You need to replace < and > with HTML entities: `&lt;` and `&gt;`